# Do not match URLs not works

Tags: css, regex

I have a CSS file, and I like to extract all the URLs in my regex editor, by replacing any other character in my CSS file with empty characterd.

The css file, looks like that:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font_name';
    src: url('http://my-site.ext/path/to/font/proximanova-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://my-site.ext/path/to/font/proximanova-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('http://my-site.ext/path/to/font/proximanova-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),url('http://my-site.ext/path/to/font/proximanova-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and I use the following regex to replace my the rest of the file conten:

```
(?!(http[^\']+)).
```

But doesn't work.

The final result I like to be like this:

```
http://my-site.ext/path/to/font/proximanova-light-webfont.eot
http://my-site.ext/path/to/font/proximanova-light-webfont.eot?#iefix
http://my-site.ext/path/to/font/proximanova-light-webfont.woff
http://my-site.ext/path/to/font/proximanova-light-webfont.ttf
```

Is there anything wrong with this pattern ?

Comment: Why not match the urls directly?

Comment: Because I don't use any programming language. I have open my Regex editor, I have paste the CSS inside the editor, and I like to remove anything excepting the URLs.

Comment: Which regex editor are you using?

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ The offline version. Note the current online version of this editor does not support replacement. If you like to see the editor I use in online version, try this http://www.regexr.com/v1/

Comment: IMO the best offline tool is RegexBuddy, and you can definitely grab the matches. You can [try it](http://yu8.us/rbdemo) for free.

Comment: FYI posted a working answer. :)

Comment: @l'L'l This matches the URLs and then it replace them.

Comment: It's ok. Anyway thank you for your interest ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will work in regex101, and maybe other online tools.

Use this regex (I escaped the forward slashes for regex101):

Search:

```
http[^\']+(*SKIP)(*F)|.
```

Replace: Empty string

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/nW3qR1), look at the bottom pane (the substitutions). Copy, paste, and you have your links.

**How it Works**

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `urls`then deliberately fails, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string. The right side matches one single character, which will be replaced by the empty string. This may sound laborious, but that's the most efficient way to do it that I know given the specs.

If you want to leave the spaces and newlines, use this instead:

```
http[^\']+(*SKIP)(*F)|\S
```

Comment: Terrific, glad to hear it! Will add a short explanation. :)